# Bulge in drywall after mounting tv

Tags: mounting, hanging, television, mount

[image]

I mounted my 60” inch tv over my fireplace and a bulge has appeared on both sides in the last few days. I’ve done some searches and it sounds like this is a “nail or screw pop”. My question is this something I need to be concerned about? Can the tv come down because of this or rip the tv and mount off the wall? I used a stud finder and there’s 4 2 3/4 lag bolts into the studs but I just want to make sure the tv is safe. The tv covers the bulge/bubble so if the integrity of the mount is fine I don’t care. Any information or advice is greatly appreciated!! [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to be concerned, assuming that your lag screw is anchored into the framing.

That's a result of a pre-existing gap behind the drywall. Maybe some insulation or a wrinkle in the vapor barrier held it out during initial hanging, and your lag screw pulled it in tight. Because there was a drywall screw there holding it out the surface bulged as the rest pulled in. There are no apparent structural concerns.

If you ever remove the tv, you'll want to put a pair of drywall screws above and below the bulge *before* removing the lag screw. Then remove the tv mount, cut away the bulged drywall and repair.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding, When you say anchored into the framing what do you mean exactly? I screwed the lags into the studs, does that mean anchored?

Comment: Anchored into framing = Anchored into studs. Same thing different words.